# search result and getting the id on php

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

i've created a medical website including a search page which i can find  different doctors according to their specialties i made it so that the result comes out in a card form and for this case i used a while loop on php as seen in the code below:

```
<?php 
 $db= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","easydoc");
 if(isset($_POST['rech']))
  {  $spec= $_POST['spec'];
      $wilaya=$_POST['wilaya'];
     $sql="select idca from cabinet where wilaya='$wilaya' ";
       $result= mysqli_query($db,$sql);
   $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   if ($resultcheck > 0)
         {     if( $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
               { 

        $sql="select * from medecin where code= $spec";
        $result= mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultcheck > 0){
        while( $rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
               { $_SESSION['mname']=$rows['lname']; 
               $_SESSION['mfname']=$rows['fname'];  
               $_SESSION['idm']=$rows['idm'];
                $_SESSION['gnd']=$rows['civilite'];
                $_SESSION['fday']=$rows['dday'];
                $_SESSION['lday']=$rows['fday'];
                $_SESSION['fhour']=$rows['dhour'];
                $_SESSION['lhour']=$rows['fhour'];
                $_SESSION['numero']=$rows['num'];
                $sqls="select nom from spec where code=$spec";
                $results=mysqli_query($db,$sqls);
                $rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
                $_SESSION['spec']=$rows['nom'];

                include("card.php");
                }} else     {?> <h3>
                <?php echo'<span style="color:red">'.'Not found ';} ?></h3>
                <?php

          }
          }else {?><h3><?php echo'<span style="color:red">'.'not Found';}?> 
      </h3><?php }
 ?>
```

[image]

it works i can access the profile by clicking on "voir profile" the only problem is i used SESSION which is causing a problem when there's alot of doctors since it's retreiving only the last one modified (soo obvious since it's in a loop soo the previous are crashed...) does someone have an idea how fix this i'm running out of time and i can't think of a clear solution for this ?

Comment: Are you trying to cache the full result in the session?

Comment: yes kinda of !! but i shouldn't !!

Comment: I also think you shouldn't. But when you do, you can store the data in a temporary variable (e.g. `$doctor`) and then add it to an array in the session: `$_SESSION['doctors'][] = $doctor;`

Comment: thank you i actually didn't know i can do an array in session !! it's all new to me but thank you !! ^^

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql1` instead of the visually similar `$sqll`.

Comment: What if you had one query instead of three?